# Database hangs when using owncloud on nginx php5-fpm postgresql - i think postgres if responsible

Tags: nginx, postgresql, php-fpm, owncloud

I have strange problem with this setup. Strangely it occurs only when using owncloud from one specific computer.

Problem is when user click on "Activities" an "document" icons one after another sometimes postgresql starts to use insane amount of cpu and site stops working (504) but only for this one specific client, other computers still can use the site.
First thing what helps is restarting nginx.

But after I learn how to reproduce this error and noticed that postgresql is using 100% of one of cpu cores. I figured out that restarting only postgresql helps too. So it must be postgres related error. But I got no trace of cause in any log files I checked

- nginx-(nginx/error.log) log connection timed out to upstream (php5-fpm I assume)
- php5-fpm log(log/php5-fpm.log ) is clear - no entries besides starting a service
- postgresql logs(postgresql-9.1-main.log) - the same

I tried update the browser on the client with no effect.
Can you point where else should I look for the cause?
Maybe I can set it up to kill/restart the database connection that is causing the problem?
I'm really out of ideas

Tried reproduce this on other computers with same Firefox and Windows 7 versions(same updates) with no success.

How can I check what postgresql is trying to do when it's working so hard and endlessly?

Configs are pretty much all defaults besides increasing `pm.max_children` for `php5-fpm` and add a `pm.max_requests = 5000` to it - that was before I notice database behaviour.
Nginxn config is straight from ownCloud docs.
Server is running Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Check `pg_stat_activity` (a system view) for the process ID of the PostgreSQL backend that's running at 100% cpu to see what it's doing and what connection is using it.

Comment: I reproduced error and did `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;` and it shows one connection besides the one I'm making query on, but no useful info. It shows database name and user but I already know that. Only curious thing is `current_query_text <IDLE>' - if it is idle why it eats all resources? How to extract/dig deeper for any useful info?

Comment: But does that entry have the pid of the one that is using all the cpu? Get the pid of the proc using cpu from top. Check if there is a pg_stat_activity entry for it. If not check pstree (with pids shown, see man pstree) and also  do a `ps aux | grep the-pid` ; add the output. To see what it is doing look into strace, getting a backtrace with gdb, or tracing with perf.

Comment: tha hanging pid is on list with text query =idle

Comment: That's weird - in that case you will need to attach to it with `gdb` and see what it's doing; see https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_a_stack_trace_of_a_running_PostgreSQL_backend_on_Linux/BSD . Or use `perf` in `-g` mode to get a profile showing what it's up to.